# How do I get an access token for Firebase Authentication?

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm using Firebase and FirebaseUI in my project. I want to give the user an options to delete his account, but if the user has been in the app longer than 5 minutes I need to reauthenticate again.

I'm not sure how to fill these parameters in the following method:

```
 + (FIRAuthCredential *)credentialWithProviderID:(NSString *)providerID
                                accessToken:(NSString *)accessToken;
```

With the credentials I can call

```
- (void)reauthenticateAndRetrieveDataWithCredential:(FIRAuthCredential *) credential
                                     completion:(nullable FIRAuthDataResultCallback) completion
```

I know the ProviderId from:

```
Auth.auth().currentUser.providerID
```

But how do I get the access token?

Comment: From a quick scan it seems that you get this from the provider. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/47338505/209103 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/38253448/209103

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I use Firebase UI 5.0. So this method: let credential = FIRFacebookAuthProvider.credentialWithAccessToken(FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken().tokenString)
does not exists anymore or something? I use the class FUIFacebookAuth, but even that FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken() returns nil when I skip login when Auth.auth().currentUser is not nil? Or do users always need to go through the login?

Comment: In FirebaseUI-iOS it seems the access token is exposed through `FUIFacebookAuth`: https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-iOS/blob/c71e037ade0dcf4bcd4e0571827059ef429fbf95/FirebaseFacebookAuthUI/FUIFacebookAuth.m#L86. I'm not sure about the exact way to access that though.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I can access it, but when I relaunch the app it is nil.

Answer (score -3):

You can call this function and get the Token!

Swift Code:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
        if let refreshedToken = InstanceID.instanceID().token() {
            print("InstanceID token: \(refreshedToken)")
        }
    }
```